# コマンドラインから、maven アーティファクトを検索するには？

Tags: maven

maven のプロジェクトを作成するときに、いちいち groupID, artifactID, version をネットで検索して pom ファイルに指定するのは面倒です。

これを、コマンドラインから検索する方法はないでしょうか。

想像としては、 apt-cache search や brew search などの、CUI のパッケージ管理システムの検索のようなものを、利用したいと考えています。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[maven, browse central repository via command line client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465721/maven-browse-central-repository-via-command-line-client)

本家にこんな質問がありました。
1つ回答がついており、
search.maven.org のAPIを叩いてレスポンスのJSONを解釈しているようです。
Groovy と Ruby 版が提案されているようですが、これなら他の言語に移植するのも簡単でしょう。

Comment: なんとなく [golang に移植してみた](https://github.com/koron/maven-search)。

Comment: やりたいことが実現できたので、accept します。ありがとうございました。